# Unity3D Windows Store App Error With Hashtables

Tags: unity-game-engine, windows-store-apps, hashtable

I am running Unity Pro 4.3.2. I have created a game that runs perfectly find in the editor. When I build this game in windows, mac, or linux standalone format, this game works perfectly fine. However, when I build this game in the Windows Store format, I get the following errors.

```
Assets\Standard Assets\Water (Pro Only)\Sources\Scripts\Water.cs(21,10): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Hashtable' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

and

```
Error building Player because scripts had compiler errors
```

How do I fix this?

I thought that $1,500 would at least get you cross platform building for water...

Any help would definitely be appreciated!

Comment: Isn't `Hashtable` deprecated?  You should be using [`Dictionary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead.

Comment: I do not know how this was coded. This is the built-in water script from Unity pro. How do I incorporate Dictionary into this?

Comment: Are you certain you're on 4.3.2? This should have been fixed already.

Comment: Did you perhaps import those assets in an older version and not re-import after you updated Unity?